# Taking unknown number of inputs without an EOF error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a_lst = []
while True:
   inp = input()
   if inp == "":
      break
   a_lst.append(inp)
```

I used this code to input unknown number of inputs in Python 3. But it gives the error "EOF when reading a line".
Is there a way to solve this? Thank you in advance

Comment: Use `try/except` to catch the EOF error.

Comment: Are you sure, this piece of code results in the `EOF` error? Because I do not get this issue.

Comment: @Thymen Did you try redirecting input from a file?

Comment: I didn't, but searching a bit further got me to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/handling-eoferror-exception-in-python/) post, that explains that EOF error can occur when there has been no data input. I do not get this issue using the Pycharm IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `try/except`

```
while True:
    try:
        inp = input():
    except EOFError:
        break
    if inp == "":
        break
    a_lst.append(inp)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

So I ran the code that you provided on my Python shell and the program works as expected:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eockh.png)

A problem that I suspect is that you're trying to run this code in a Python file rather than the shell. The `input()` function looks for a filename to read from. Because you're writing `input()` without a filename, the function doesn't know what input it's looking for and thus you get the EOF error.

Comment: `input()` doesn't need a filename. It reads from standard input, which is normally the terminal but can be redirected to a file or pipe.